# Do MSMQ fit for this scenario? EmailSending Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, msmq

I am newbie to MSMQ.
Here is my scenario:
Once the bill is generated by Billing Software, I need to send emails to all customers with guaranteed delivery(quickly).
Below are the possible things we need to take care of:
1. **If Internet is down then there should be capability of retry sending after some time.**

2. **Order of Email sending** 

3. **Ability to process/send emails on Priority.**

I have knowledge on Service Broker(MSSB).

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on your scenario a bit more? For example is your Billing Software a website, desktop app, web service etc? And describe your requirements a bit more - they seem a bit vague to me so I could not recommend one technology over another at the moment

Comment: Billing Software is webservice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address point number 1 in your question, if you have many instances of the billing software in different locations, then you can create a single 'central' service responsible for sending e-mails (lets call the machine that hosts that service ServerX). In this scenario the main issue that you need to address is ensuring ServerX has constant access to an SMTP server (which will be sending the e-mails). So ideally ServerX should have a very reliable and stable connection to the internet or if your SMTP server is on your own network, then ServerX must have 
unhindered access to the SMTP server on your LAN. Now if your software which is producing the bills that you want to send to your customers is in a disparate location 
(away from ServerX) then you can use MSMQ to ensure that the e-mail requests sent by the instances of the billing software are actually getting delivered to ServerX. Basically your billing software will then make calls to the MSMQ service on ServerX rather than the SMTP server directly, MSMQ here can act as a mediator which will pass the received messages to the SMTP server. This is a feasible and easily implementable service if the architecture you have in mind is what I mentioned above. You could instead have every instance of your billing software make calls to the SMTP server-though this way you are inducing extra obstacles for yourself and creating multiple possible points of failure rather than reducing them.

Once you have your instances of the billing software make calls to ServerX, then the remaining points you mentioned (2 & 3) become simple formalities and can easily be addressed through simple business logic in your service on ServerX.

So to sum up, I would go about doing it like this:

1. Create a central service (using MSMQ) which will receive and process your your e-mail requests.
2. Ensure that the server hosting the MSMQ service has reliable access to an SMTP server.
3. Have your billing software send the e-mail requests to that central MSMQ service rather than directly to an SMTP server.
4. Process the requests as you wish on the central server, i.e. whenever you receive a new message on the queue, invoke your e-mail sending service.

Though having said all that, this was just a recipe to fit MSMQ into the scene, I can't be too sure if it's the best thing for what you're looking to do, but this is one way you can intergrate it into your enterprise.